# How can I detect referrer using jquery with custom url patterns

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, referrer

I am developing a functionality for my site, where I want to check if the user is being referred from a particular address. I have some url patterns as below -

- website.com/*
- website.com/products/*         ( * as product name )
- website.com/*/my-category  ( * as category slug )
- *.website.com                       ( * as sub-domain )
- website.*                               ( * as domain extension )

There are more url patterns like this. I want to detect if the user is coming from any of this url pattern and display a custom message on my site for that user.

How can I achieve this?

I am getting the referrer using the following code - 
`var doc_ref     = document.referrer.toLowerCase();`

Please help me to get this done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging into the code for a while, I found the following code is working for me -

`var url = 'mysite.com/plugins/*';
    var doc_ref     = document.referrer.toLowerCase();
    var url_arr = url.split("*");
    var _domain = url_arr[0];
    if( url.indexOf('*') !== -1 ) {
        if( _domain == doc_ref ){
            display = true;
        } else if( doc_ref.indexOf( _domain ) !== -1 ){
            display = true;
        }
    }`

Hope this will help anyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can run some Regexes on the value or use indexOf, and do some actions based on them.

For example (not final code):

```
if (doc_ref.indexOf('my-category') != -1) {
     //user came from my-category
}
```